# short issue: gulpfile.js should be in .gitignore?

Tags: gulp

I am newbie at frontend development :)
Here is my short question.

I assume that at this point gulp is only for developing, not deploying.
And, typically, build folder and node_modules are include in .gitignore. So, is it better to put gulpfile.js to .gitginore?

or is there any other use of gulpfile.js when source code is deployed ?

Comment: How are you planning to deploy your code? If you deploy with `git pull` on the deployment server, you will need to run `gulp` because your build folder should be ignored.

Comment: so basically everytime I renew my deployment, I has to run gulp to build my project?

Comment: The server typically builds for you. The dependencies gulp and the project in general needs will be installed by the server with npm install. So you might want to move gulp to dependencies rather than devDependencies.

Comment: Ah ha that is why both Devdependencies and depedencies exist. And then I have to install node modules in server computer. Now I got it. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 7):

You should keep in `.gitignore` files, which you don't want to be stored in your git repo, for example `node_modules` dir.

`gulpfile.js` should be inside of your repo, as it required dependency for building your project

Comment: Thanks 1ven!

Your answer occurs serial  questions. We know `gulpfile` import some of `node_modules` which is ignored by git. can gulp build my project without node_module when it is deployed? (btw I use Django for backend.)

Comment: @namwoo after you clone your project(or your teammate), the next step is to run `npm install`, which will install all dependencies of your project into the created `node_modules` dir